# How to add 1.1.1.1 for Families to Windows 11?

Tags: dns, windows-11, anti-malware, cloudflare

I'm able to use 1.1.1.1 with Windows 11, but when I try 1.1.1.2 or 1.1.1.3 then Windows doesn't suggest any DNS over HTTPS template. How do I use 1.1.1.2 and 1.1.1.3 with Windows 11 *without installing the WARP app*?

[image: 1.1.1.3 as preferred DNS without automatic template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DoH addresses](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1-for-families#dns-over-https-doh) are:

- `https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query` for malware blocking (1.1.1.2).
- `https://family.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query` for malware and adult content blocking (1.1.1.3).

You can add these as *automatic templates* using the PowerShell cmdlet [`Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/add-dnsclientdohserveraddress) (run as admin).

```
# Block malware
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 1.1.1.2 https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 1.0.0.2 https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 2606:4700:4700::1112 https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 2606:4700:4700::1002 https://security.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True

# Block malware and adult content
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 1.1.1.3 https://family.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 1.0.0.3 https://family.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 2606:4700:4700::1113 https://family.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
Add-DnsClientDohServerAddress 2606:4700:4700::1003 https://family.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query -AutoUpgrade $True
```

The `-AutoUpgrade $True` makes non-secure requests also being sent over DoH.

---

Screenshot after adding them:

[image]